# Div expanding vertically infinitely

Tags: css, html

I have a page that Im creating where the main menu is on the left hand side of the page, and I want it to fill up the entire left side.

Example image:

[image: Sample image]

The blue part is the logo, main menu, copyright area.
The darker grey part is where the main content will be.

Right now I have it coded out so that the dark grey area is actually the html element styled to have that grey gradient and the blue area is a div that I have floated left. The problem I run into is that when the grey area has enough content in it where you have to scroll down, the left div doesnt extend with it.

I want the blue and grey areas to stay static.

HTML:

```
<body class="clearfix">

    <div id="left">

        <div id="logo">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" /></a>
        </div><!-- END logo -->

        <div id="mainNav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="aboutMe.html">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="contactMe.html">Contact Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Portfolio</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- END menu -->

        <div id="copyright">
            &copy; 2014
        </div><!-- END copyright -->

    </div><!-- END left -->

    <div id="right">
    </div><!-- END right -->

  </body>
```

CSS:

```
html {
background: #333132 fixed center top;
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0b0b0b 0%, #333132 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0b0b0b 0%, #333132 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0b0b0b 0%, #333132 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0b0b0b 0%, #333132 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #0b0b0b 0%, #333132 100%);
 }

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#left {
    width: 300px;
    min-height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background: #316b9c fixed center top;
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #316b9c 0%, #194980 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #316b9c 0%, #194980 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #316b9c 0%, #194980 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #316b9c 0%, #194980 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #316b9c 0%, #194980 100%);
    box-shadow: 3px 0px 5px #0b0b0b;
    margin-right: 50px;
    position: relative;
}

#logo {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

#mainNav ul {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

#mainNav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#copyright {
    color: white;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: You can put an enclosing div around both, use overflow: auto; and put the div you'd like to expand without content on height: 100%.

Comment: I added overflow: auto and height: 100% to the #right div and that seems to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to close of your div tags you have started with the id's ="right" in your HTML markup. You also need to define CSS values to the #right parameter in your CSS.

Comment: They are closed in my markup, that was just a copy paste error.